# Server not running tasks in parallel when dev machine does

Tags: .net

I have a very CPU intensive .net application that runs quickly on my Dev machine (a laptop with an 8 core i7 processor). When I run the same application on my server (a newer i7 processor with 8 cores) it appears to only access one core when looking at the basic windows resource monitor / task viewer.

The laptop has Windows 10 installed, and the application is in Release mode. The server is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

Here's the concurrency report for my dev box:

[image: Dev concurrency report]

And for my server:

[image: Server concurrency report]

You can see they are very similar. However, on my dev box the process takes 19 seconds whereas on the server it takes 90 seconds.

There little to no disk io - the system is basically performing calculations on a set of in memory data structures.

Any thoughts on how to start tackling this problem gratefully recevied!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a tip in an obscure Microsoft document suggesting that you change the power plan on the server to High Performance, which seems to have done the trick.